# Is there any difference between synchronized(UserDefine.class) and symchronized(define1.getClass())?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java MutliThread these days,I met a problem.Is there any difference between synchronized(UserDefine.class) and synchronized(define1.getClass())?

```
define1 is an instance of UserDefine class.
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

If `define1` stores a reference to an object of concrete type `UserDefine`, no there is no difference. Both the expressions

```
UserDefine.class
```

and

```
define1.getClass()
```

will result in the same `Class` instance. There would therefore be no difference.

If `define1` stores a reference to an object of any other type (or `null`), then there will be a difference. The corresponding thread will lock the monitor on a different object or a `NullPointerException` will be thrown (for the `null` case).

Answer (score 3):

Minor difference:

`UserDefine.class` will *always* reference the UserDefine.class object
`define1.getClass();` may, in your case, always return UserDefine.class, but often in programming, if you or someone else comes along later, possibly subclassing UserDefine, in your code it may not return what you expect.